# Styling only to last index of an Array in typescript React?

Tags: arrays, typescript, react-native, styling

The only idea I have now is

```
if (customFields.values[0]) {
    <View style={styles.borderContainer} />; }
```

For this array

```
let customFields: Array<{
              value: any;
              label: string;
            }> = [];

  if (query.data) {
              customFields = query.data.current_squad.custom_fields
                .filter(
                  (customField) =>
                    customField.is_visible_on_squads &&
                    customField.custom_field_value.value
                )
                .map((customField) => {
                  return {
                    value: customField.custom_field_value.value,
                    label: customField.title,
                  };
                });
              }
            }
```

But that doesn't work obviously.
The end goal is to make a border at the last place in the array which is based on however many custom fields one makes.
I am new to frontend and JS languages so any pointer to the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` higher-order function takes an index parameter, but you need to get your list length after `filter` function and before `map` function:

```
const exampleResult = custom_fields
  .filter(
    (customField) =>
      customField.is_visible_on_squads &&
      customField.custom_field_value.value
    )
)

const listLenght = exampleResult?.legnth;

const result = exampleResult
  .map(
    (customFiled, index) => {
      if(index === listLength -1 ) {
         return {
           value: customField.custom_field_value.value,
           label: customField.title,
           style: {styles.borderContainer}
         };
      } else {
         return {
           value: customField.custom_field_value.value,
           label: customField.title,
         };
      }
    }
  )
```

As another solution, you can add the style property to the last item after `filter` and `map` method:

```
const customFields = someData.filter(() => {}).map(() => {}) // just pseoudo

const lastItem = customFields[-1];

customFileds[-1] = {...lastItem, style: {styles.borderContainer}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering I really appreciate it. I am currently working it out with one of my group members and we will have to change some of the other code to make it work out but this is really helpful.

Comment: it's my pleasure @thinBillyBoy , good luck bro.